# Space Projection of singular matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, numerical-linear-algebra, projective-space, projection-matrices

Describe the space that $A$ projects onto and the space that $A$ projects along$$A = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\0&1 \end{bmatrix}.$$

A matrix, $M$ is a perpendicular projection operator on the column space of $M \iff MM = M $ and $M = M^T.$ Clearly, $A$ does not satisfy this theorem. How do I describe the space that $A$ projects onto and the space that $A$ projects along? I need help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to check that $A$ projects, that is $A^2=A$. That is true.

Then the subspace it projects to is the range of $A$ (I hope you can find it) and the space it projects along is the nullspace of $A$ (you should be able to find it too).

Comment: I appreciate your help

Comment: You can probably accept the answer.

Comment: Can yo take a look at this question I posted here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3804609/column-space-and-orthogonal-complement/3804859#3804859. I will appreciate your help there too

Comment: The second answer there is correct. The first one is totally wrong provided $n\ge 2$ and rank$(A)<n$

Comment: You mean the answer provided by Draditate is correct?

Comment: No, the answer  by Christoph is correct.